# PHP Script Delaying SMS Messages Being Sent?

Tags: php, scripting, sms

I am currently running a PHP script that queries the database and then sends text messages (via carrier's email-to-sms gateway).

In other words, I have the phone numbers stored in the DB as:

```
1234567890@txt.att.net
1236547890@vtext.com // etc...
```

My method for sending these is using the Swift Mailer PHP Library.  I am sending the message using "SMTP", and using the SMTP account from my Host Provider to send it out.

Typically, using this SMTP account, I will send no more than 30-40 text messages in 1 minute.

Here's my question:

I have noticed that when I send these text messages, many times it appears to work fine, however, lately it appears that some users receive the text messages maybe an hour (or several) later.

I understand that once it leaves my server, it is up to the carrier to decide when to send it.  However, could it possible that something in my script causes the issue?

For example, I have noticed that in some parts of the DB, a user's number will be displayed as:

```
  1234567890  //notice, no '@vtext.com' or whatever
```

Could issues like this cause the delay of other emails/texts?

Finally, does anyone know of any script or way to build a script that can query a cell phone number and determine who the carrier is?

Many thanks on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can only be answered if you provide us the code, what you have done. I can give you a tip. Try to send the message with the previous timestamp so that your carrier server processes them first.